# Mono for Android Installation didn't proceed..!

Tags: android, installation, xamarin.android

I've downloaded the setup file "1.5 MB" from xamarin.com/trial ..I'm using Windows 7 and have VS 2010 installed..

when I run the setup file It shows the first screen only and disappears suddenly before showing the next screen..

what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to turn it off and on again?

Answer (score 1):

Its most probably the firewall/anti virus blocking the install from reaching out to its server. Check their logs or try disabling them by turns to see what is causing it. It seems that the setup program is an executable rather than a proper setup